# coding with several IF conditions or is SWITCH-CASE might be good here?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am having a `vector<ClassA>` (say `my_vector`, this *ClassA itself is vector of ClassB*), and I want to write `if condition` to test the conditions such that

> (1). If only one element is not empty while all others are empty, (as
>        size of the my_vector is five, I should test this non-empty one
>        element  case one after the other for e.g. my_vector[0], my_vector[1],..)
>
> (2) also, if two of elements are not empty while others are empty
>       (similarly for other pairs)
>
> (3) similarly, three or more of elements are not empty

I am thinking how to code this

this is my try

```
if (!my_vector[0].empty() && my_vector[1].empty() && my_vector[2].empty() && .. &&  
         my_vector[4].empty()){ //process 1}
else if (!my_vector[1].empty() && my_vector[0].empty() && my_vector[2].empty() && ..){ 
         //process 2}
else if(!my_vector[2].empty() && my_vector[0].empty() && my_vector[1].empty() && ..){
        //process 3}
...
...

else if (!my_vector[0].empty() && !my_vector[1].empty() && my_vector[2].empty() && ..   
         my_vector[4].empty()){ //process n}
else if (!my_vector[0].empty() && !my_vector[2].empty() && my_vector[1].empty() && ..   
         my_vector[4].empty()){ //process n+1}
....
....
else if (!my_vector[0].empty() && !my_vector[1].empty() && !my_vector[2].empty() &&    
         my_vector[3].empty() && my_vector[4].empty()){ //process p}
....
like wise
```

**this is really hard way to test, any methodical way to do this.**
thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the pairing of your elements matter? For instance, if `my_vector[0]` will your code treat the case `my_vector[1]` is also empty any differeny from if `my_vector[2]` is empty instead?

Comment: @newfurniturey: basically, I should do a certain process, if one element is not empty and at the same time all others are empty, also when 2 of are non empty while others are empty,.... But I should do this for all possible cases

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the [count_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) template function from `<algorithm>` and a lambda, you will obtain a compact and clear solution:

```
unsigned int non_empties = std::count_if(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), [](const ClassA & c) { 
     return !c.empty();
});

if (non_empties == 1) {
  // process 1
} else if (non_empties == 2) {
  // process 2
} else if (non_empties >= 3) {
  // process 3
}
```

The `<algorithm>` library is surprisingly often neglected, while it offers really practical solutions like this.

Answer (score 1):

If the pairing of empty/not-empty elements don't matter, you could iterate through your collection to get a count of how many are empty:

```
int size = my_vector.size();
int emptyCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    emptyCount += (my_vector[i].empty() ? 1 : 0);
}

if (emptyCount == 0) {
    // no elements are empty
} else if (emptyCount == 1) {
    // only one element is empty
} else if { emptyCount == 2) {
    // two elements are empty
} ...
```

In the end, with this method, you'll still need an if/else-if for each condition; however, this could be expanded to use percentages (if your collection grows to a random-size).

Answer (score 0):

Define an array of patterns (conceptually a 2D array of `bool`).  Then iterate through each row in turn, and find the one that matches.  Then call the relevant function corresponding to that row (you'll probably want an array of function pointers).

Comment: thanks for the reply. but could not able to undestand. i am new to c++... any simple explanation or example please

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the new c++11 functions all_of, none_of can help you here.

So you can do something like this

```
auto iter_begin = my_vector.begin();
auto iter_end = my_vector.end();
auto is_empty = [](decltype(*iter_begin) const & param){ return param.empty();};
auto is_not_empty = [](decltype(*iter_begin) const & param){ return !param.empty();};

if(iter_begin->empty() && all_of(iter_begin + 1, iter_end, is_empty ))

else if(all_of(iter_begin, iter_begin + 1, is_not_empty) && all_of(iter_begin + 2, iter_end, is_empty))

else if(all_of(iter_begin, iter_begin + 2, is_not_empty) && all_of(iter_begin + 3, iter_end, is_empty))
```

and so on

Comment: Well then get a newer compiler for Dev C++... I think you can use any version of g++ available for windows.

Comment: @slinga, Dev c++ is not a compiler. It's just an IDE, that uses some external compiler. If you'll update a compiler (I think, that it's either GCC or MinGW) you'll have all C++11 features in your Dev C++

Comment: @borisbn: thank you. it is a useful idea. i think it is mingw... not sure something like g++ also inside with me. any specific way to update them?